# Config not found in /home/$USER/.kube/config

Tags: kubectl, k3s

When I run `k3s kubectl version`

```
$ k3s kubectl version
W0730 19:46:32.066086   17273 loader.go:222] Config not found: /home/ecarroll/.kube/config
[...]
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another error message relate to your kubectl config. In this case you likely have an environmental variable `KUBECONFIG` pointing to a location that doesn't exist.

First confirm this is set to the same location above that didn't exist

```shell
echo $KUBECONFIG
```

If it's already set, simply regenerate a kubeconfig for k3s with

```shell
mkdir ~/.kube 2> /dev/null
sudo k3s kubectl config view --raw > "$KUBECONFIG"
chmod 600 "$KUBECONFIG"
```